# Getting whole commit message of a reset commit

Tags: git, version-control

How do I get the whole commit message of a commit which I hard reset?

There could be a way to do it using `git reflog`, however, do we have another way?

Comment: If you in fact deleted this commit, then yes, using the reflog is a good way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `git log -g` to walk back through your previous HEADs, but it will not have information about why HEAD moved.

You could read the logs straight from `.git/logs/HEAD`. That won't show you anything `git reflog` won't, but it might be easier to develop a tool to find the IDs of resets.

`git reflog` will show all your previous HEADs (the commits you had checked out) in order and why HEAD moved. `git reflog` takes all the same options as `git log`. For example, you can get more context with `git reflog --pretty=medium` to see the full commit messages. However, it's probably easier to get the commit ID from `git reflog` and then the commit message with `git log <that id>`.

A reset should be easy to spot. For example, here is a `git reset --hard HEAD^1`.

```
70cc722 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD^1
5cbd5ea HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
```

Comment: And you would then checkout the commit id of that line. `git checkout 5cbd5ea`.

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine No need to check it out to get the commit message, only need to `git log 5cbd5ea`

Comment: I did not read that from your answer, though I understand it is indirectly said in walking back through `git log -g`. I had not thought it would be so easy, good.